# notification on nokia S40

Tags: java-me, push-notification, nokia-s40, java-micro-editon-sdk3.0

Good day!

I am doing an IM application on S40 phone using JAVA ME. I would like to know, when the application is closed, how to get notify(promt a dialog with the message and icon on the status bar) when a new message arrives. I tried with push notification but it doesn't help me, Although I can wake my application up with the network(push with socket), I can't have either a dialog(prompt dialog when notification occurs) with an custom message nor set icon on status bar.

Thanks